# trouble with fragment when using android maven plugin

Tags: android, android-maven-plugin

I have an android project with maven integrated, plugin part here

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>13</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>both</debug>
                    </sign>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>                    
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

everything goes well, just after I have integrated the Fragment it stop building from mvn command line.

I have checked and in the aapt call the android library is present...\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-13\android.jar

I get a few errors containing

```
... cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Fragment
location: package android.app
```

as a compile error on mvn clean install

I could switch to using support library, but I would prefer to use the android.app.Fragment. Has anyone a clue what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the version and I update the version of android plugin as well to 4.1.1.4

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```